# Vertical scroll not working for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Designed table and tried to make vertical scroll bar for limited 5 data. Had declared scroll in css but it is not working. tried to make fixed header table and tbody scroll. When more row added into the table then tbody(td) should scroll. Used width in % due to adjust the every row data and had tried a code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Theme CSS -->
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ">
      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
      <script
         src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
      <script
         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
      <script
         src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
      <style type="text/css ">
         table{
         width: 800px;
         position: relative;
         }
         thead { 
         display: block;   
         overflow-y: auto;
         height: 30px;
         max-width: 100%;
         top: 0;
         font-size: 12px;
         }
         tbody {
         max-width: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         top: 40px;
         height: 2em;
         overflow-y:scroll;
         display:block;
         font-size: 10px;
         }
         table.scroll {
         width: 100%; /* Optional */
         /* border-collapse: collapse; */
         border-spacing: 0;
         border: 2px solid black;
         }
         table.scroll tbody,
         table.scroll thead { display: block; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <div class="container ">
      <table class="scroll table table-bordered  ">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="width: 2.5%;font-size: 12px; ">Sl No</th>
               <th style="width: 3%;font-size: 12px; ">First Name</th>
               <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Middle Name</th>
               <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Last Name</th>
               <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Email</th>
               <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Department</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">1</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">12</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">3</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">4</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">5</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">6</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">7</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">8</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">9</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
               <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code, this will introduce a vertical scroll in your code

```css
.scroll {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon " href="img/favicon.ico ">
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
  <style type="text/css ">
    table {
      width: 800px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    thead {
      display: block;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 30px;
      max-width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    tbody {
      max-width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      height: 2em;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      display: block;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    table {
      width: 100%;
      /* Optional */
      /* border-collapse: collapse; */
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    table tbody,
    table thead {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="container ">
  <div class="scroll">
    <table class=" table table-bordered  ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 2.5%;font-size: 12px; ">Sl No</th>
          <th style="width: 3%;font-size: 12px; ">First Name</th>
          <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Middle Name</th>
          <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Last Name</th>
          <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Email</th>
          <th style="width: 10%;font-size: 12px; ">Department</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">1</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">12</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">3</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">4</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">5</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">6</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">7</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">8</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">9</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">User</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">Name</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px;">Unknown</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">username@gmail.com</td>
          <td style="font-size: 11px; ">IT Development</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No its not working. Scroll doesn't exist. It resembles my same my code.

Comment: I apologize. Inserted the wrong snippet. Please try now.

Comment: I am trying to make only tbody scroll. I mean td.

Comment: Please try using this fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/hh6etg6s/". Should serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think you need two tables, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7ry2bas8/).

```
 <!-- table for header -->
 <table class="table table-bordered mb-0">
   <thead>
     ~
   </thead>
 </table>

 <!-- div for scroll -->
 <div class="scroll-area">
   <!-- table for data -->
   <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tbody>
       ~
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

I like this way because it's really flexible.
However, if you want to show the scroll bar(I mean, take the width for the scroll bar), this way might be not good.

If the layout is simple, you can use [position: sticky](https://jsfiddle.net/0zxkL4c3/).

```
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
```

I hope they will help you.